# Xamarin error when trying to look for add-in

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have just installed Xamarin Studio Community on Mac OS X.

In the menu, when I open `Xamarin Studio -> Add-ins -> Updates/Gallery` and click `Refresh` , I get the following error:

> Could not get information from repository:
>   http://addins.monodevelop.com/Stable/Mac/6.1.4/
>
> **Details**
>
> Exception occurred: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not
>   Found.
>
> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404)
>   Not Found.   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00065] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1025
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1037
>   at MonoDevelop.Core.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse
>   (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0008d] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3509/e606823f/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core.Web/RequestHelper.cs:194

Does anyone know what the cause of this issue could be?

Comment: I could quite easily reproduce the issue. When expecting the details, I got a `(404) Not Found.` Conclusively, this seems to be an issue on Xamarin's end. Fo that reason, you should consider filing an entry on [their bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/).

Comment: Also, this post is a [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41653876/2399772).